# Python modules importing behavior

Tags: python, import, module

Can someone explain this behavior?

A.py:

```
import B
values = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    values.append('something')
    print(values)
    B.printValues()
```

B.py:

```
import A

def printValues():
    print(A.values)
```

Result:

```
['something']
[]
```

I expected:

```
['something']
['something']
```

Comment: The `import A` in `B` is *from the file*, and **doesn't** run the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block (the *whole point* of which is that it doesn't run on `import`), so `B` sees the original (empty) `values`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: I'm with OP. This is how I see it: 1. `A` imports `B`, which in turn imports `A`. 2. `'something'` is appended to `values`. 3. `B.printValues` is called. 4. `A.values` is accessed, which should be `['something']`, but isn't. How come `B`'s `A.values` differs from `A`'s `values`?

Comment: interesting.  I guess jonrsharpe is correct, but I thought that modules were only loaded once, so B's reference to A was the same as A itself, including the values list.  Must not be the case after all.  On a side note, you probably know that A import B, B import A is a circular import and not necessarily best practice.

Comment: ah, I wonder if the import A aspect isn't the key here.  A, when run is __main__, it doesn't consider itself loaded in the modules.  When B runs it imports A, which does load in the modules.  It happens to be the same A.py, but one is main executing pgm, the other one is a module and will not be reloaded.  id(values) gives two different outputs, from A and B.

Comment: @JLPeyret: You're right, `A` is executed twice, once due to `import A`.

Comment: @senshin.  related, but not a duplicate.  the link you are referring to is concerned with the ' __name__ = "main" ' guard code to limit execution to main only.  As I see it, the OP's observed behavior is more generic in nature and concerns namespacing in sys.modules vs in '__main__', as Hiroki says.  Sorry, not totally clear with my explanation, but best I can find to express.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens:

1. `A` imports `B`. This causes the code in `B` to be executed:

   1. `A` is imported. Because this is the first time `A` is being imported (`A` is not in `sys.modules`), all the code in `A` is executed.

      1. `import B` is executed. This does **not** execute the code in `B`, because `B`is already in `sys.modules`.
      2. The empty list `values` is created.
      3. the `if __name__=='__main__'` block is **not** executed, leaving `values` empty.
   2. `B` now has a reference to a module `A` **that differs from the main module**. You can confirm this by adding `import __main__; print __main__ is A` to `B`. It will print `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am pretty sure A as main is not the same as the one in import A which ends up in sys.modules.  So A exists *twice*, once as main, once as a module.  Added a third module, C and you see that the B to C semantics meet your expectation - B and C share a common A.

A.py

```
import sys
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):A top"
import B, C
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):A after import B, C"

values = []


if __name__=="__main__":
    values.append('something')
    print "A:", values, 'id:',id(values)
    B.printValues()
    C.printValues()
```

B.py

```
import sys
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):B top"
import A
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):C after A import"

def printValues():
    print "B:", A.values, "id:", id(A.values)
```

C.py

```
import sys
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):C top"
import A
print len(sys.modules), "len(sys.modules):C after A import"

def printValues():
    print "C:", A.values, "id:", id(A.values)
```

and this all outputs:

```
 42 len(sys.modules):A top
 43 len(sys.modules):B top
 44 len(sys.modules):A top
 45 len(sys.modules):C top
 45 len(sys.modules):C after A import
 45 len(sys.modules):A after import B, C
 45 len(sys.modules):C after A import
 45 len(sys.modules):A after import B, C
 A: ['something'] id: 4493313232
 B: [] id: 4493269616
 C: [] id: 4493269616
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is a kind of closure.

you can add `print` any place to observe import behavior.

A.py

```
print("before import B")
import B
print("start execute A as " + __name__)

values = []

if __name__=="__main__":
    values.append('something')
    print "values=" + str(values)
    B.printValues()
    B.appendValue("hello")
    B.printValues()
    print "values=" + str(values)

print("finished execute A as " + __name__)
```

B.py

```
print("start runnig B")
import A

def printValues():
    print "A.values=" + str(A.values)

def appendValue(new_value):
    A.values.append(new_value)

print "A.values=" + str(A.values)

print("finish running B")
```

it gives result

```
before import B
start runnig B
before import B
start execute A as A
finished execute A as A
A.values=[]
finish running B
start execute A as __main__
values=['something']
A.values=[]
A.values=['hello']
values=['something']
finished execute A as __main__
```

`A.values` seen from B.py is another instance of data.
It is not A.py's `values`. there is another namespace between combination of program & `__name__`.