# Importing functions from different modules - python

Tags: python, import

I am importing a function - func,  from a module - mod, using

```
from mod import func
```

And using it as

```
X=func(x,y)
```

but before executing the function my program is executing the whole module.
How do I make it to execute only the function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid module execution put the code in the module under `main`

```
# stuff to run always here such as class/def
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   main()
```

more complete answer:
[Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: If there is a *"more complete answer"* on another question, please flag or vote to close as duplicate.