# Inheritance answer overlap

Tags: python, inheritance

I have to make a program that converts a string to pig latin and include an constructor + example of the program. I then have to make a subclass based on it with a overwritten method to add a few new rules.

In the original class file I have the constructor:

```
pig = pigLatin_Class("First test")
print(pig)
pig.sentence = "Changing it up"
print(pig)
```

Which works correctly, however in my new subclass:

```
gib = gibberish_class("test")
print(gib)
```

Which also works correctly but prints out the answers from the super class as well, even though they're outside of the class definition.

I'm using:

```
import assignment_a3_1 as a3_1

class gibberish_class(a3_1.pigLatin_Class):
```

as my inheritance.

Any solutions?

EDIT:

In regards to the naming conventions, I'm just using what we were told to use, also I've only been coding for a month or two at most, doing a uni course, be gentle! :D

Super:

```
class pigLatin_Class(object):

    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]

    def __init__(self, initialSentence):

        self.__sentence = initialSentence
        self.sentencePig = []
        self.pLatin_converter(self.__sentence)

    def pLatin_converter(self, sentence):

        wordList = sentence.split(" ")

        for word in wordList:

            isVowel = False
            wList = list(word)

            for character in word: #vowel checks
                if(character in pigLatin_Class.vowels):
                    isVowel = True
                    break

            if(isVowel == False): #finishing if no vowels
                wList.append(wList.pop(0))
                word = ''.join(wList) + "way "
                self.sentencePig.append(word)

            if(''.join(wList) == word): #Stops it from iterating through again if it contains no vowels

                if(wList[0] in pigLatin_Class.vowels):
                    word = ''.join(wList) + "hay "
                    self.sentencePig.append(word)

                elif(wList[0] not in pigLatin_Class.vowels): #contains vowels but not first

                    for i in range(len(wList)):
                        if(wList[i] in pigLatin_Class.vowels):

                            wList = wList[i:] + wList[:i]
                            word = ''.join(wList) + "ay "
                            self.sentencePig.append(word)
                            break


    def __str__(self):

        string = ("\n The translation of '" + self.__sentence + "' is: " + ''.join(self.sentencePig))
        return string

    @property
    def sentence(self):
        return self.__sentence

    @sentence.setter
    def sentence(self, value):
        self.__sentence = value
        self.sentencePig = []
        self.pLatin_converter(self.__sentence)


pig = pigLatin_Class("First test")
print(pig)
pig.sentence = "Changing it up"
print(pig)
```

Subclass:

```
import assignment_a3_1 as a3_1

class gibberish_class(a3_1.pigLatin_Class):


    symb = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",",",".","/",";","#","[","]","=","-","(",")","*","&","^","%","$","£","_","+","{","}","~","<","@",":","?",">","<","|"]
    vowels = a3_1.pigLatin_Class.vowels

    def pLatin_converter(self, sentence):

        wordList = sentence.split(" ")

        for word in wordList:

            suffix = 0
            isVowel = False
            wList = list(word)

            for character in word: #vowel checks
                if(character in gibberish_class.vowels):
                    isVowel = True
                    break

            if(isVowel == False): #finishing if no vowels
                wList.append(wList.pop(0))
                suffix = 1

            if(''.join(wList) == word): #Stops it from iterating through again if it contains no vowels

                if(wList[0] in gibberish_class.vowels):
                    suffix = 2

                elif(wList[0] not in gibberish_class.vowels): #contains vowels but not first

                    for i in range(len(wList)):
                        if(wList[i] in gibberish_class.vowels):

                            wList = wList[i:] + wList[:i]
                            suffix = 3
                            break


            for character in wList:
                #print(character)
                if(character in gibberish_class.symb):

                    wList.append(character)

            if(suffix == 1):
                word = ''.join(wList) + "way "
            elif(suffix == 2):
                word = ''.join(wList) + "hay "
            elif(suffix == 3):
                word = ''.join(wList) + "ay "

            self.sentencePig.append(word)





gib = gibberish_class("test")
gib.pLatin_converter
print(gib)
```

EDIT TWO:

The another question was very helpful in stopping the main method, however the **str** method is still called in the first question, just printing an empty string, said if statement just causes the program to throw errors if used in the **str** method. How would I solve that?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: It seems that what you need is not to _add_ new rules, but to _replace_ the whole set of rules with new rules. If you had a method that implemented (combined) all the rules, you would override that method. Also, please name your classes using `CapitalCamelCase`, it's a near-universal convention in Python.

Comment: can we see the classes?

Comment: The classes are in, will look into examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: Right, so that fixed it in part, it no longer runs the method, but it still prints the string through __str__, and sticking an if __name__ == "__main__": in there just caused python to crash, just with the result being a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton of how a typical program like yours could look.

```
class PigLatin(object):

  def __init__(self, text):
    ...

  # Add helper methods to taste.

  def splitIntoWords(self):
    return ...  # re.split would help here.

  def mangle(self):
    # Do your conversion, put it into result
    ...
    return result


class Gibberish(PigLatin):
  # No __init__ since you inherit it.

  def mangle(self):
    # This method replaces, aka overrides, mangle() of PigLatin.
    # You can use other methods, e.g. self.splitIntoWords().
    ...
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
   text = 'Hello world!'
   print 'Do you know what "%s" would be in Pig Latin?' % text
   print 'It is %s' % PigLatin(text).mangle()
   print 'And now some Gibberish: %s' Gibberish(text).mangle
```

Hope this helps.