# Is there a way to import items from a file without running all of the code in that file in python

Tags: python, import

I have two files, file1 and file2.

files 2 is this:

```
print "Why is this printing"

var = 7
```

file 1 is this:

```
from file2 import var

print var
```

When I run this code, it outputs the following:

```
Why is this printing
7
```

Is there a way I can obtain `var` from `file2` without running the code above the declaration of `var`?

Comment: Put the statements in functions

Comment: and use `__name__`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want code to run when a module is imported, put it in a function:

```
def question():
    print("Why is this printing")
```

If you want the function to run when the module is passed to the python interpreter on the command line, put it in a conditional expression block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    question()
```

e.g.

```
c:/> python file2.py
Why is this printing
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks!  I am wondering:  Why does the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it use that 'main' function - it looks like it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's an example. If you want the program to do something, replace `pass` with the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

guard to protect some lines from executing on importing. This condition is satisfied only if you run that particular file, not import it.