# When importing a module in python it reads everything in that module first and then the current .py However i only want the data saved in a function

Tags: python

When I import  module Task_3 in python it reads everything in Task_3  first and then the current Task_4.py However i only want the data saved in a function. 
I have already tried to do from Task_3 import Songs_list() but its just doing the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: Can you post a simple example of the problem? Why would it matter that python reads and compiles the module? You asked for an import, you got an import. @Aran-Fey is almost certainly right about the dup, but we don't have enough information to know.