# Importing function from another .py file imports more than just that function?

Tags: python

To illustrate the issue I am having, please consider the following. I have two .py files, one named `main.py` and the other named `mymodule.py`. They are both in the same directory.

The contents of `main.py`:

```
from mymodule import myfunction

myfunction()
```

The contents of `mymodule.py`:

```
def myfunction():
    for number in range(0,10):
        print(number)

print("Hi")
```

I was under the impression that importing a function would only import that function. However, when I run `main.py`, this is what I get:

```
Hi
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Why is `print("Hi")` being called? It isn't part of the function I imported!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was under the impression that importing a function would only import that function.

It seems there's an incorrect assumption about what a from-import actually does.

The first time a module is imported, an import statement will execute the entire module, including `print` calls made at the global scope ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)). This is true regardless of whether the `mymodule` was first imported by using a statement like `import mymodule` or by using a statement like `from mymodule import myfunction`.

Subsequent imports of the same module will re-use an existing module cached in `sys.modules`, which may be how you arrived at the misunderstanding that the entire module is not executed.

There is a common pattern to avoid global level code being executed by a module import. Often you will find code which is not intended to be executed at import time located inside a conditional, like this:

```
def myfunction():
    for number in range(0,10):
        print(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hi")
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to import something from the module Python needs to load this module first. At that moment all the code at module-level is executed.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function
>   definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module.
>   They are executed only the first time the module name is encountered
>   in an import statement.

Comment: I would have add the footnote too: `In fact function definitions are also ‘statements’ that are ‘executed’; the execution of a module-level function definition enters the function name in the module’s global symbol table.`

Answer (score 3):

this question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it).

In short : all the code of a python file is called when importing the module. What is neither a function nor a class is usually put in a *main* function called here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   main()
```

Please consider closing this thread.