# Importing from python interactive mode

Tags: python, import, interactive

I ran a script using "python -i" from the command line. The script ran as I expected and I end up in interactive mode, as expected.

Now, however, I want to use a command from the scipy.signal package, so I type:

```
>>> from scipy import signal
```

For some reason, this triggers the interpreter to run the whole script again from the start.

Why does this happen? And how should I avoid it?

Comment: Is your script file named `scipy.py` perhaps?

Comment: If not, what filename did you use? It is probably being imported somewhere.

Comment: the script was named timeit.py, which is apparantly a python module. However, I changed it to test.py and the same thing keeps happening:
`$ python -i test.py
Calculate Spectral Densities
Correlate
time np.correlate() : 0.04867911338806152
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py:501: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>>> from scipy import signal
Calculate Spectral Densities
Correlate
time np.correlate() : 0.05021977424621582
>>> `

Comment: Sorry, that formatting looks aweful. Basically, the _Calculate Spectral Densities Correlate time np.correlate() : 0.04867911338806152_ part is output of the script (the number being the computational time using the time-module, so it's not an issue if the numbers aren't the same)

Answer (score 1):

When you import a file the whole file is read in and executed. This is the same whether you use `from file import function` or just `import file`.

You should place any code you don't want to run when it is imported in a block like this:

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    your code here
```

Your function definitions that you wish to import should be outside this block, as they need to be loaded and executed to be imported and available for use.

See [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it) which explains this in further detail.

Comment: I am importing the scipy.signal module, which is a signal processing module (which I did not write): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html