# Why does importing a variable from another python file run all code in that file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a file called test1.py with the following code:

```
print("HELLO WORLD")
x=999
```

I have another file called test2.py with the following code:

```
from test1 import x

print(x,"hello!")
```

Why is this the output:

```
HELLO WORLD
999 hello!
```

Why does it perform the function in test1 instead of just getting me the variable `x`?

In test.py I have tried:

```
from test1 import x as a
print(a,"hello!")
```

This gets me the same output.

Expected result:

```
999 hello!
```

Actual result:

```
HELLO WORLD
999 hello!
```

Sorry if this was a repeated question - I just can't find a solution.
EDIT: This was marked as a duplicate earlier - one problem with that: using `if __name__ == "__main__"` logic prevents me from accessing any variable in main. I just want a variable without running the file.

Comment: Can we see more of your code, how did you import it?

Comment: That is all the code - I didn't do anything fancy here, I just want to get the value for x into test2.py without running the code in test1.py

Comment: in test1.py you should have `x` in a separate function. Then importing `x` would look something like `from test1 import function`. Write the function so it returns `x`. `x` will now be an attribute of test1

Comment: Yes that solved it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

modules are executed on import. If the modules contains code you dont want to be executed on import you can wrap this code with an if-block `ìf __name__ == "__main__"`.

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm
(found in [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)
)