# Importing Python function from other file executes the other file

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I import a function from a Python file, I don't want it to be executed whole. I only want the function to be imported. Currently when I import the function, the a.py file gets executed.

a.py

```
def func():
    print("inside func")


print("outside func")
```

b.py

```
from a import func

func()
print("in B")
```

Output

```
outside func
inside func
in B
```

Expected/wanted

```
inside func
in B
```

Comment: Maybe see here: [Maybe see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: When you import a module, all it's code gets executed. Instead, you should design your modules to be used as a library.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the print call in `a.py` in a `def main():`, then add

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

to the bottom of a.py. This will prevent the print from being called unless `a.py` is run directly.