# Python Import Functions withtout executing script

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a python script named `script_A`. I need a function present in another script named `script_B` located in the same directory as `script_A`.

When I execute `script_A`, everything goes well until the commands importing the function are executed: `script_B` is executed.

I just want to benefit from the use of the function in `script_A` and do not want  `script_B` to be executed.

Here is my code :

```
from script_B import my_function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 1):

Bro this happens internally see understand when you call a function from another module you just pass the necessary arguments so the function in that particular script has to run in order to provide you the output.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the answer relies on using the command:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    my_function()
```

When importing the script, `my_function()` will not be executed and I will benefit the use of the functions defined in the script.