# Why is Hello printed only two times?

Tags: python, module, sys

**main.py**

```
#main.py
import main
print('Hello')
```

**Output**:

```
Hello
Hello
```

I believe that when it comes to the line `import main`, at that time, `main` is registered in `sys.modules` and hence the import statement of another script - *which I believe, is not a part of `__main__`* - is not executed. Can someone please tell me whether I understand it correctly? If not, please give an explanation.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `main.py`?

Comment: @Aramakus I have posted it already.

Comment: So..are you trying to do some kind of recursive printing of `hello` here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: @Roland Deschain I guess it's cyclic import.

Comment: OK, only a guess here, but I would say you can only import stuff once...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's add a little debugging output:

```
import sys
print([key for key in sys.modules.keys() if 'main' in key])
import main
```

It prints:

```
['__main__']
['__main__', 'main']
```

Why is that?

If you run a module it will **not** be added as its modules name to `sys.modules`. Instead it will always be `__main__`.

If you then import the module by its name (`main`). That name is not present in `sys.modules` and as the result the module will be imported again, its code executed and the modules stored in `sys.modules` under its name.

On executing `main.py` it will print `['__main__']` and on the re-import it will print both module names: `['__main__', 'main']`.

This implies one rule: try not to import the module you are running anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It only prints it twice because a module is only actually loaded once. This prevents possible unbound recursion. So your print statement gets executed once by the imported module and once by the main program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're importing main inside main the print statement is executed twice,thats how python works

Comment: I may be wrong, but I feel like the question is not WHY it is printing twice, but it is ONLY printing twice. Thus, OP knows about this feature

Comment: but the code can only print hello two times,there are no other print statements

Comment: I get it now he asks why it isn't calling main again and again,the question should be edited to why it is not looping then