# Issue with import in python

Tags: python, python-import

So, I'm quite new to python, and I tried to import a function that I had written in one of my files into another file that I was working on.

Here is the code in the file that I'm trying to import the function from:

```
def print_me(x):
    return 2 * x

print(print_me(5))
```

Here is the code in my other file:

```
from question2 import print_me

print(print_me(5))
```

Now when I run my second file, the answer (10) gets printed twice.
I want to know the reason why my print function in my first file (from which I imported my function) also gets executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When import a module, in fact you're importing the whole codes from that file, including `print` statements and others.

In order to reach this, you should either remove `print` statement in the first file where you define `print_me` function, or add this code to your file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # your code goes here
```

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file, every statement in this file is executed. Therefore both the `def` statement and the `print` function call are executed, printing "10" once. Then the code from your other file is executed, printing "10" a second time.

The proper way to deal with this issue is to put all the code that shouldn't be executed on import inside this block:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # code that should not be executed on import
```

This ensures that the code from the first file is only executed when run.