# Importing Classes from another file

Tags: python, class, import

I'm trying to import the User class from a file called gui.py into another called snake.py. I want to import the class so that I can use ,a method within the class and an instance of the class called current_user. But when I do:

```
from gui import User
```

It imports everything from gui.py. Does anyone know where I've gone wrong and what I can do to fix this?
I'm new to working with multiple files in Python and this is quite confusing to me.
The files for this are available at:
https://github.com/VladRadoi08/Snake-LoginUI

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: So doing the if __name__ = "__main__" should stop running the gui.py code and only import the class? Did I understand that okay?

Comment: yes, put a `print` inside and outside the if if it helps you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything in the file you import will be run.  To prevent this, try putting all the code you don't want to run within this conditional:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

That will ensure it only runs if you actually run the python file instead of importing it.