# How to loop N times python script by another python script?

Tags: python

For example I have in PyCharm:

Script1.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=pl&gl=PL")
time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
```

Script2.py

```
import YtTest.py
import time

i = 0
while i < n:
    execfile("YtTest.py")
    i += 1
```

How to make import properly and execute Script1.py and loop it N times (all in Script2.py)?

Comment: Put the logic in `Script1.py` into a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, one would use a function for this

You can run the script independently by clever use of the `__name__` property too

script1.py

```py
def my_function():
    "whatever logic"

if __name__ == "__main__":  # this guard prevents running on import
    my_function()
```

script2.py

```py
from script1 import my_function

def main():
    for _ in range(10):  # run my_function() 10 times
        my_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code style is extremely useful for a variety of import-related activities, such as [unit testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function in script 1 like this:

Script1.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

def my_func():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=pl&gl=PL")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_func()
```

Script2.py

```
from script1 import my_function

i = 0
while i < n:
    script1.my_function()
    i += 1
```

To adapt with your needs.