# Run a python script forever

Tags: while-loop

I want to run my script

> control_as_py

forever. I tried

```
while True:
    import control_as_py
```

but for some reasons, it runs the script ones and then stopps. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code that you want to run inside a function.
in `control_as_py`

```py
def dostuff ():
   #Write here what you want to run forever
```

in `main.py`

```py
from control_as_py import dostuff

while True:
    dostuff()
```

Comment: But if I want to run the whole script, not just the functions?

Comment: Then you can wrap the whole code of the file `control_as_py` in a `while True` loop

Comment: okay, thanks. But can you explain why it´s not working the way I did it?

Comment: From now on im just assuming, but i think it runs only once because it needs to import things in that module, so in the future its loaded.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it) can help you.