# Is there a way so that a statement doesn't run at the start of a program?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, python-2.x

I am making an MS-DOS operating system in Python, and I want the user to select an application to run.

```
print("""
[1] Open notepad
[2] Open file explorer
[3] Configure BIOS
[4] Exit OS safely
""")
select = input("[?]: ")
if select == '1':
    execfile('edit.py')
if select == '2':
    execfile('file.py')
```

But `edit.py` runs first.

I tried assigning select to 0 at the start of the program, expecting select to not be anything (hence, no app runs), but it didn't work.

```
select = '0'
...
print("""
[1] Open notepad
[2] Open file explorer
[3] Configure BIOS
[4] Exit OS safely
""")
select = input("[?]: ")
if select == '1':
    os.startfile('edit.py')
if select == '2':
    os.startfile('file.py')
```

Comment: What do you mean by ``edit.py runs first`` ?

Comment: What do you mean, "edit.py runs first"?

Comment: Do you have an `import edit` statement somewhere?

Comment: yes, I've written import edit at the start of the program

Comment: Cubix48 edit.py runs at the start of the program and everything runs after it.

Comment: When you `import` something, it runs the script. You'll need to wrap your code you don't wish to run in a function or `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)