# Python: the meaning of "importing sub-modules might have unwanted side-effects" in docs

Tags: python

The [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) say:

> 6.4.1. Importing * From a Package
>
> Now what happens when the user writes from sound.effects import *?
> Ideally, one would hope that this somehow goes out to the filesystem,
> finds which submodules are present in the package, and imports them
> all. This could take a long time and importing sub-modules might have
> unwanted side-effects that should only happen when the sub-module is
> explicitly imported.

What does "might have unwanted side-effects" mean?

Comment: I think it may be due to loosing the "where" function/classes are from: if you have 2 different `from x import *`, function/classes names can be overwritten and everything just breaks

Comment: Python will evaluate and run a module the first time you import it. If there's any code with side effects in the module (for example `print()` calls) those will happen. Read the answers to this question to see some examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it

Comment: @HåkenLid, thanks, the examples are helpful. I'm still confused by the wording of the docs "...might have unwanted side-effects that should only happen...". Why the *unwanted* side-effects are expected (should) happen?

Comment: If you mean `from x import *`, this will import all the modules in that package -> hard to debug since ydk where it all comes from.

Comment: @HåkenLid, the links you provided do explain the confusion; and if you make this the answer, I will accept it. Or close this question as a duplicate.