# How to import dependent code from two modules?

Tags: python, import

I have the following situation:

The first file, named `a.py` contains:

```
var = 2
```

The second file, named `b.py` contains:

```
def prnt():
  print(var)
```

The third file, named `c.py` contains:

```
from a import *
from b import *

prnt()       # NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

and raises the given error. I always thought that the `import` statement basically "copies" code into the calling namespace, so it should be the same as:

```
var = 2

def prnt():
  print(var)

prnt()
```

but apparently this is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: ```var``` is defined in ```a.py``` but you aren't importing ```var``` in ```b.py``` which is where you use ```var```.

Comment: use `global var` as the very first line inside your function.

Comment: Functions remember the module they were defined in and take their "global" (actually module-bound) variables from there.

Comment: Please do not shift the focus of the question via edits once the original has been addressed by answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module, the code in that module is run by the interpreter (see [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6523791/3381305); add a print statement in there and you'll see it in action). Therefore you can't use variables etc without defining them or importing them.

In `b.py` do this at the top:

```
from a import var
```

Then, unless you need `var` in `c.py`, you won't need to import anything from `a.py` in `c.py`.

I know this is fake code, but avoid using globals in your functions.

Comment: thank you for the hint, but now I'm even more confused about how the interpreter works under the hood (see my edited question)

Comment: You aren't importing the module's code as 
text into the current program, you're running the module's code in the current runtime.