# prevent class instantiation from original file path when importing

Tags: python

Here is the project folder structure:

```
foo/
├─ foo/
│  ├─ foo.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
__main__.py
```

```
# foo.py
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.origin = os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

```
# __init__.py
from .foo import Foo
```

```
# __main__.py
from .foo import Foo
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_foo = Foo()
    print("\twant:", os.path.realpath(__file__))
    print("\thave:", my_foo.origin)
```

When I run `python -m foo` from outside the root, I get:

```
        want: ...\foo\__main__.py
        have: ...\foo\foo\foo.py
```

Since `Foo()` is being instantiated inside `__main__.py` I assumed, `__file__` would point to the path of `__main__.py`. That does not seem to be the case. What do I need to do to make sure the second line (`have`) is the same as the first line?

Maybe my problem is in the same vein as [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6523791/7128934), but those answers did not work for me.

Comment: `__file__` refers to the file containing the code that references that name.  If you want the name of the file that instantiated an object, you'd need to pass `__file__` as a parameter to the instantiation.

Comment: @jasonharper, that's what I ended up doing. I need to pass `__file__` from all places where I import `Foo`. Is there no way to avoid that?

Comment: You can also use the `inspect` module like here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack