# Importing a .py file opens it on startup of another file

Tags: python

I am importing a settings.py file into browser.py, like so:

```
import settings
```

But when I run the browser.py file then it opens settings.py before it runs browser.py, and I don't want settings.py to run. Is there a way to stop settings.py from running, while still importing settings into browser.py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: when settings.py run, what it return ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any python code outside functions and classes will be automaticly ran when you import the settings file.

You can try put the code that you don't to be executed inside a function in the settings file and then calling those functions in browser.py as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

You want to check in your `settings.py` file to see if that file was run directly by the user, or if it was included by some other module.  The way to do that is with the `__name__` variable.  That variable is always defined by Python.  If you are in the file that was run directly, it's value will be `__main__`.  So, in `settings.py`, do something like the following:

```
<code you want to always have take effect, usually functions, class definitions, global variables, etc.>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    <code you only want to run if this file was run directly>
```

It is common to use this mechanism to provide some test code for a module.  Here's simple concrete example of that:

```
def some_function(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

def test():
    some_function(123, 234, 456)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

So this just defines `some_function` and `test`, but doesn't run them if it is included by some other Python file.  If it is run directly, then `test()` is run to test the `some_function()` function.