# from file1.py import function, how to remove the code unexpected?

Tags: python

I have two files: file1.py and file2.py

file1.py

```
print("34343433")

def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import print_hello

print_hello()
```

the output of file2 is:

```
34343433
Hello
```

I just want to have it print only the "Hello" portion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file in Python, all code in the file is run (even in partial imports), including the print statement you had. To remove the extra numbers, you have two options:

1: Remove the code

```
#file1.py
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

2: Put it into its own function

```
#file1.py
def print_nums():
    print("22132322432")#Call this with file1.print_nums()
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

In both of these cases, running file2.py will only produce the output `Hello`. If you want a way to detect if file1 is being imported, see Alex Grounds' answer.
Hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

As Enderbyte mentioned, when you `import file1` (or for that matter `from file1 import print_hello`), all code in that file is run. However, there is a way to check if this file is being run directly, or being imported instead:

```py
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("34343433")
    # add other code if desired
```

Then `print("34343433")` will *only* run if `file1` is invoked directly via `python file1.py`. When it's imported, that print statement will not execute.